# Tableau: Cumulative Change Chart from Daily Changes

Tags: tableau-api, cumulative-line-chart

I have data that contains date and percent change [chg] in my data.

I would like to create a chart that is a cumulative change, which means (1+chg) * previous value.

In order to accomplish this, I use the following:

```
   if  
   INDEX()=1 then 1
   ELSE (1+sum([chg]))*PREVIOUS_VALUE(1)
   END
```

The problem with this format is that it cuts off the first day's data.

Is there a way for me to include the first day's data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1+sum([chg]))*PREVIOUS_VALUE(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I need them to start at 1. The best solution would be to add a value before the first available value and start it at 1.